# C# How to create an instance from a given reflection Type from a list of Type in a Combo-Box

Tags: c#, user-interface, reflection, drop-down-menu, instance

`List<Type> BotNames = typeof(BotPlayer).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BotPlayer))).ToList();`

I've put that list into a combo box to be displayed to the user in the drop-down menu. I'm trying to create an instance of the selected item of the combo box which is a subclass of a class called BotPlayer and is meant to make use of a method called "Move" which is present in the class and all its subclasses. I'm also trying to pass that instance into a BotPlayer variable called Bot. I've tried the different ways of using Activator.CreateInstance but it doesn't seem to work for me or I don't understand it enough to implement it into my own program. This was the furthest I was able to get

```
Bot = (BotPlayer)Activator.CreateInstance((Type)Difficulty.SelectedItem);
```

When I run my program it gives me this error: "System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'"

This is the code for the combo box which exists in the Designer.cs

```
            this.Difficulty.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.Difficulty.Items.AddRange(BotNames.ToArray());
        this.Difficulty.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(205, 181);
        this.Difficulty.Name = "Difficulty";
        this.Difficulty.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 21);
        this.Difficulty.TabIndex = 3;
```

This is the code for the combo box which exists in the normal cs file

```
        if (Difficulty.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Bot = (BotPlayer)Difficulty.SelectedItem;    //This is called casting
            Bot.Type = BotType;
            //Bot = (BotPlayer)Activator.CreateInstance((Type)Difficulty.SelectedItem);
            //Bot = (BotPlayer)Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", "BotPlayer");
        }
```

This is the BotPlayer Constructor

```
       public BotPlayer(GameBoard board, SquareValues type)
    {
        Type = type;
        Board = board;
       // Difficuty = difficulty;
    }
```

This is the constructor for all its subclasses

```
    public BotPlayer1(GameBoard board, SquareValues type) : base(board, type)
    {
        Board = board;
        Type = type;
        BotName = "Level 1";          
    }
```

The only difference between the subclasses is the number at the end of BotPlayer and the bot name which is equivalent to that number with the word "Level" behind it

Comment: Can you show the code that poulates the combo?

Comment: You didn't actually say what the (observed) problem is. Frame the call of Activator.CreateInstance in a `try`-`catch` block and see whether it throws any exception (check the documentation for Activator.CreateInstance, it can throw quite some different types of exceptions)

Comment: sorry about that @elgonzo, I just added in the exception i got

Comment: "_No parameterless constructor defined for this object_" is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it? Activator.CreateInstance can only create instances of types that have a parameterless (public) constructor (i.e., a constructor without arguments). Clearly some (if not all) of your BotPlayer classes lack such a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Can you post the constructors for `BotPlayer` ?

Comment: By the way, _Activator.CreateInstance_ also has method overloads which allow creating object instances using constructors that require arguments. Like this one, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___. But this would of course require your code to be able to provide valid argument values for that constructor when calling Activator.CreateInstance...

Comment: @elgonzo But then how would I make it work so that it actually creates an instance of the Bot selected from the drop-down menu of the combo box. I tried different method overloads but none of them seem to work (or at least I'm unsure on how to properly use them). The one I used was the one that seemed to work the best (by this I mean it didn't create a compile error).

Comment: @Neil I've now edited it to show the constructors

Comment: @Jumpman, have all your BotPlayer classes the same kind of constructor with the same number and types of parameters (i.e., `SomeBotPlayerClass(GameBoard board, SquareValues type)`)? If not, think how you can improve your BotPlayer classes so that you can implement a parameter-less constructor in them...

Comment: Could you have different classes (with parameter less constructors) for each type of bot. Then they could all call the Base class initialise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bot = (BotPlayer)Activator.CreateInstance((Type)Difficulty.SelectedItem,Board,BotType);
```

I found that all I needed to do was pass in parameters into the Activator.CreateInstance.

Thanks to @elgonzo and @Neil for helping me realize this.